# Cant login more than one user Facebook Parse

Tags: facebook, authentication

Hi I'm using the Parse Login Ui to let the user log into the app with facebook.
(https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui-login)
This is working nicely, however when the user logs out, 
and a different user tries to log in on the same device an error message is displayed, saying that the App is not correctly set-up.
It is as if the App is hard coded to be used by only one user (the first one to use it).

Any ideas how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Bart

Answer (score 0):

found the answer
on https://developers.facebook.com/apps
you have to set the app to
'live and available to other users'

my bad :)